# `indexOf` returns unexpected result on list of groovy.Gstrings

Tags: groovy, indexof, gstring

When running `indexOf` on a list of Gstrings, the return value is always `-1` despite an expected index match:

```
mystr = "foo"

// expect .indexOf to return 0
println "${["${mystr}_bar", "baz"].indexOf("foo_bar")}" // -1
println "${[mystr + "_bar", "baz"].indexOf("foo_bar")}" // ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​0​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Am I misunderstanding something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use:

```
["${mystr}_bar".toString(), "baz"].indexOf("foo_bar")
// or if you have many: ["${mystr}_bar", "baz"]*.toString().indexOf("foo_bar")
```

(note the explicit `.toString()` there).

`GString` look the same (e.g. they `.toString()` to their current state)
like `String`, but they aren't.  E.g. you can have a closure inside
a `GString` or a call to generate a random number.  They are not
immutable or "stable" like their `String` brothers.  That e.g. is also
the reason, why they are unfit to be keys in maps.  So they *equal* the
same, but they *hash* different.

Comment: Thanks, and reading up on this a bit more, I'm guessing that this is because `.indexOf` uses `.equals` internally. I had found by chance that `["${mystr}_bar", "baz"].findIndexOf{it -> it == "foo_bar"}` works. Now that I've read about the differences between `==`, `.equals`, `.compareTo` and `.is` this makes a lot more sense!